# How can I get a list of Class Assignments using the Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-edu

When I execute this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var assignments = await graphClient
  .Education
  .Classes["classId"]
  .Assignments
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

It returns this error:

> IEducationClassRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Assignments' and no extensible definition method...

But call the following from [Graph Expolorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) returns the expected list of assignments.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/{id}/assignments
```

Any pointers, please? Running out of hair to pull out LOL, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`educationAssignment` resources and endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationassignment?view=graph-rest-beta) are still in Beta and therefore not included in the main [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

In order to access Beta resources/endpoints, you'll need the [Microsoft Graph *Beta* .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet).